# Google autocomplete Places API error InvalidValueError

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, google-maps, google-places-api

```
function wnw_set_google_autocomplete_my(){
    jQuery(gaaf_fields_my).each(function(){

        var autocomplete_my= new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(this),
        { types: ['geocode'] });
        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
        // populate the address fields in the form.

    });
}
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    wnw_set_google_autocomplete_my();
});
```

link: http://35.154.204.251/contact/

I have installed Google autocomplete Place api in wordpress and i am getting InvalidValueError in the console and i am not able to figure out the problem because every thing is looking fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the value of variable `gaaf_fields_my`. When I put a break point I can see that this variable has a following value

`" [name="input_2"], [name="demo"], #input_2_2, #demo, .address, .demo"`

The issue is that `jQuery(gaaf_fields_my)` returns as a first element an `<li>` element that has class 'address' and is not an `<input>`. This leads to exception in autocomplete constructor that expects an input element as a parameter, but you try to initialize it on `<li>`.

[image]

You should apply a better selector or check inside jQuery loop a tag name of the element before calling the autocomplete constructor:

```
 function wnw_set_google_autocomplete_my(){
     jQuery(gaaf_fields_my).each(function(){

         if (this.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {

             var autocomplete_my= new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
                 /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(this),
                 { types: ['geocode'] });

         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Working Fine :)